# Windows form c# para autoCAD - "No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado"

Tags: c#, windows-forms

me encuentro programando mediante windows form para automatizar algunas funciones de autoCAD, estoy intentando abrir autoCAD y que me cambie el nombre de varios Text en varios archivos que tengo; pero al momento de dar click en el boton que programé para abrir autoCAD me aparece el siguiente error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'accoremgd, Version=21.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado
>   cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.'

Básicamente estoy usando este código para abrir archivos existentes con c# pero con una windows form, no .dll:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-330A8DCB-626F-4271-8B89-9773A7631D87-htm.html

```
using System.IO;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

[CommandMethod("OpenDrawing", CommandFlags.Session)]
public static void OpenDrawing()
{
    string strFileName = "C:\\campus.dwg";
    DocumentCollection acDocMgr = Application.DocumentManager;

    if (File.Exists(strFileName))
    {
        acDocMgr.Open(strFileName, false);
    }
    else
    {
        acDocMgr.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage("File " + strFileName +
                                                        " does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ese ensamblado que tira error, esta en tu proyecto?

Comment: Cuando dices que ejecutas desde Windows Forms posiblemente no esté claro si al abrir lo haces con la Api de AutoCad. 1º Deberías echar un vistazo a la tabla de compatibilidad entre las versiones: http://gilecad.azurewebsites.net/AutoCAD_VisualStudio.aspx  y luego echa un vistazo al mensaje nº 9 de https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/clr-detected-invalid-program/td-p/8164292    Es posible que te ayude bastante

Answer (score 0):

también tuve ese problema, y al parecer era a que estaba trabajando con la opción de Consola, corregí ese problema trabajando con Librería de Clases.

Comment: Hola, Jimmy. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. No uses, por favor, el apartado de respuestas para colocar comentarios y/o agradecimientos. Podrías usar la sección de comentarios de la persona que hizo la pregunta. Saludos.